# Show that $\mathbb{C}[x, y]_{d-1}$ is spanned by $\left\{\frac{(\prod_{j=1}^d l_j)}{l_i} \middle| i = 1, \dots, d\right\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let $\mathbb{C}[x, y]_{d-1}$ be the set of homogeneous bivariate polynomials of degree d-1 and $l_i=a_ix+b_iy$ with $a_i,b_i\in \mathbb{C} ~\forall i$. Show that $\mathbb{C}[x, y]_{d-1}$ is spanned by $\left\{\frac{(\prod_{j=1}^d l_j)}{l_i} \middle| i = 1, \dots, d\right\}$. Someone told me that this is a Lagrange basis so it's quite trivial, but I don't find any good reference to know what is a Lagrange basis and how to show this is one. Moreover, show that by multiplying by $x$ or $y$ the generators we obtain a spanning set for $\mathbb{C}[x,y]_{d}$.

Comment: How are the $a_i$ and the $b_i$ chosen ? It is not always a basis, take for example all $a_i$ equals 1 and all $b_i$ equals 0. It is even more non sense if for an $i$ we have $a_i = b_i = 0$. Once you have the right condition on the $a_i$ and $b_i$, try to show that your family is free and you obtain your result by equality of dimensions since $\mathrm{dim}(\mathbb{C}[x,y]_{d - 1}) = d$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P_i=\prod_{j\neq i} \ell_j$, then these polynomials span $\mathbb{C}[x,y]_{d-1}$ iff the points in $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^1$ corresponding to the homogeneous coordinates $(a_i,b_i)$ are all distinct, i.e., iff for all $i<j$ we have
$$
\left|\begin{array}{cc}a_i & b_i\\ a_j & b_j\end{array}\right|\neq 0\ .
$$
To show that take a linear combination $\lambda_1P_1+\cdots+\lambda_d P_d=0$. Then plug for $(x,y)$ the values $(b_i,-a_i)$, $i=1,\ldots,d$, succesively.

This is just a homogenized version of how to prove the Lagrange polynomials are linearly independent if the interpolation points are distinct.

**Remark:** (a bit more involved) One could also take the homogenized Wronskian of the $P_i$ and show it is a constant multiple of the homogenized Vandermonde of the linear forms $\ell_i$, i.e., the product of all the above $2\times 2$ determinants.